# Is it possible for me to check if something is printed to the terminal

Tags: python

I'm making hangman, and I want to check that if "Yay you solved the puzzle" is printed then the function returns ""

```py
def hangman(word):
  tries = 8
  user = ""
  for i in range(tries):
    user_input = input("Guess the word?:" )
    if user_input in word:
      user += user_input
      if user == word:
        print("Yay, you solved the puzzle")
        break
      else:
        print("Thats correct, keep going")
      tries += 1
    elif user_input not in word:
      print("Oops that's wrong")

 #Here I want to check whether "Yay, you solved the puzzle" is printed, then subsequently return ""
    
print(hangman("salsa"))
```

Comment: Make a variable like `solved = False` at the start, and set `solved = True` if they solve it.

Comment: set a flag in the loop.  After the loop, check if the flag was set.

Comment: Instead, I'd return `True`/`False` from the function, then print any messages based on that later. It's possible to intercept the STDOUT, but it would be probably the most difficult way of achieving what you're trying to do.

Comment: Can I ask why you three would not elect to just return what OP wants to return?

Comment: @7koFnMiP I wouldn't because then you need to do a string comparison later to verify, which is slower, and opens the possibility of the string being compared against being "out of date" if the string in the function is changed. Might as well return True/False which can never change, and is dirt-cheap to check (although efficiency I this particular case doesn't matter).

Comment: @7koFnMiP Also, the function as specified by the OP would return `""` for success and `None` for failure to guess the word. That's not explicit at all, and both evaluate to `False` in boolean context.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just do an empty `return` after `user == word`:

```py
def hangman(word):
  tries = 8
  user = ""
  for i in range(tries):
    user_input = input("Guess the word?:" )
    if user_input in word:
      user += user_input
      if user == word:
        print("Yay, you solved the puzzle")
        return
      else:
        print("Thats correct, keep going")
      tries += 1
    elif user_input not in word:
      print("Oops that's wrong")
```

I will leave this answer up as it solves OP's question about wanting a way to return if `if user == word` is satisfied, but it is definitely worth noting the discussion in the comments which points out that returning `None` will probably cause issues later on and returning `True` would be better